# Retrieving JSON Objects from a text file & printing each objects from the file in each row Using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a text file which consists of Nested JSON Structure, I need to pick the objects from the file and print it in separate file in row wise fashion. For Example,

Let's say that

I have a array of records inside my JSON file

```
object: [{"ID":198888,"sub":"nnn","topic":"python"},{"ID":19889,"sub":"nnj","topic":"jython"}]
```

I have to parse above file and reprint the objects in another file as

```
{"ID":198888,"sub":"nnn","topic":"python"}
{"ID":19889,"sub":"nnj","topic":"jython"}
```

This has to be done in Python

Comment: is `object:` actually in the file?  If so, it's not valid JSON...

Comment: And what problems have you ran into so far? You have a JSON list there, it's not hard to parse that with the `json` module, and write out each separate value with a newline in between to another file.

Comment: This is rolled into Python already and it is pretty well documented.  http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html

Comment: have a look at the help(json) from your terminal >>>

Answer (score 0):

See this question ...

[Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Have information of your question. @mgilson is correct. You need extra caracters for parse your "string" see below:

```
import json
>>> data = json.loads('{"object": [{"ID":198888,"sub":"nnn","topic":"python"},{"ID":19889,"sub":"nnj","topic":"jython"}]}')
>>> data
{u'object': [{u'topic': u'python', u'ID': 198888, u'sub': u'nnn'}, {u'topic': u'jython', u'ID': 19889, u'sub': u'nnj'}]}
```

This method access the first object of data `object`

```
>>> data['object']
[{u'topic': u'python', u'ID': 198888, u'sub': u'nnn'}, {u'topic': u'jython', u'ID': 19889, u'sub': u'nnj'}]
```

This command access the first item of `object`

```
>>> data['object'][0]
{u'topic': u'python', u'ID': 198888, u'sub': u'nnn'}
```

This command access the second item of `object`

```
>>> data['object'][1]
{u'topic': u'jython', u'ID': 19889, u'sub': u'nnj'}
```

[Data Structures Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is good reading to understand how Python works.

Answer (score 0):

[Python's built-in json library](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html)

look into json.loads() and json.dumps()